Google play console warning about Content labeling and Touch target size Issue
I'm trying to "production publish" my app from Google Play through Google Play Console that stuck on reviewing, My app was build using Unity3D engine, and its game app, for some reason I'm facing the warning issue about Content labeling and Touch target size Issue maybe because this issue, my app hasn't approved or declined by google because it says:

Warnings found. We recommend fixing before releasing to production.

I've search about this, and it's an issue that can be fixed only inside Android Studio on XML file with this structure res>layout, however there is no layout folder inside the res, is there anything I can do to resolve this issue on Unity?
currently using Unity LTS 2022.3.12f1
What I've done

Export unity project to android studio.
Try to add some code on the layout, but can't since there is lack of layout folder.

Preview

The warnings from Google Play console




Project structure from Android Studio



Code markdown is meant for code and discretionarily for code like things. It is not meant for general emphasis. More information is available here.
